# Why does Babel 6 some (unnecessary) code transformations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In this simple Babel (6.1.18) example `babel --presets es2015 test.js` transforms:

```
'use strict'; // enable strict mode

(function () {
    const A = 3;
}());
```

to

```
'use strict' // enable strict mode
;
(function () {
    var A = 3;
})();
```

It's mostly out of curiosity but I would be interested to better understand why:
- the location of the semicolon in the first line has been moved into a separate line
- the syntax of the iife has been changed from `(function () {}());` to `(function () {})();`

Comment: It's not really that it has decided to transform this code when it could have left it as is... it's that Babel always uses a specific syntax to output specific constructs. Your input is destructured into an abstract syntax tree, then reassembled into Javascript code. The "assembler" here is hardcoded to output these specific cases as it does. That's all. You may ask why it outputs things in this specific format, but worrying about why specifically this input was transformed into specifically this output is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An **Abstract** Syntax Tree does not retain formatting information, e.g. whether the calling parenthesis are outside or inside the grouping operator. In fact, the grouping operator (`(...)`) is [not even represented in the AST](http://astexplorer.net/#/iI7GEjh3JV).

That's why people are working on a [**Concrete** Syntax Tree implementation](https://github.com/cst/cst), which would contain such information and what could then be used by code generators to stay closer to the original source code.

There are tools which are able to reuse the original code if that part of the code didn't change (e.g. [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast)), but because Babel primarily focused on transpiling code for the browser, this was probably of less importance. This may change now that Babel became more of a platform.

Comment: This is exactly what I was interested in. Babel regenerates the code from the AST. It obviously was more my wishful thinking in assuming that Babel uses the least intrusive approach when transpiling my code. I guess nobody will really care but I would very much appreciate an "recast like" approach where only the absolutely necessary changes are made and my code remains as much "my" code as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Babel is a transpiler and works in a very similar way to a compiler:

[image]

1. Babel performs lexical analysis on your code. This means it gets tokenized. `(function(){})()` becomes a stream of tokens such as `"(" "function" "(" ")" ...`
2. babel creates a syntax tree. The linear stream of tokens representing your program is converted into a tree like this one: [image]
3. babel then performs semantic analysis on your code. This is when it checks for errors, makes sure your code is legitimate ECMA6 code, adds missing semicolons and makes sure the syntax tree is a legitimate program
4. babel generates javascript code from the syntax tree

So you can see that there are a few ways you might be able to write the same code, however when semantical analysis and code generation are performed, the same code is generated.

Comment: I do understand how Babel works but would have hoped that it is less intrusive when not needed. I used my given example to show 2 cases when Babel actually did not have to transpile anything. The syntax tree of my file already contained a 'use strict' statement and the iife generated the same code.

Comment: Well, but `(function () {}());` has a different syntax tree than `(function () {})();` - it's not just whitespaces. So there must be something else going on.

Comment: @Bergi: It's the same syntax tree, at least following the ESTree spec.

Comment: @FelixKling: So ESTree omits the grouping operator? OK, that seems reasonable.