# Why Babel parses IIFE of arrow function

Tags: javascript, babeljs, iife

As I may see from grammar of ES2015 this expression is not a valid one:

```
() => { console.log("hello"); } ();
```

You need at least put parentheses:

```
(() => { console.log("hello"); }) ();
```

Chrome fails on first sample with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

But Babel is ok with that. Why?

Comment: Uh, no, where do you read in the grammar that it was not valid?

Comment: Because babel transpiles your code nicely? I think it's rather like this that your chrome doesn't support ES2015 (ES6) yet, or you didn't activate the developer extensions

Comment: If you use the code directly in Chrome's console, it will be parsed as if it's ES5. Babel loads the .js code via ajax and transpiles it (so, Babel "understands" ES6 and translates it to ES5).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, only I cannot find it. Anyone?

Comment: @Bergi I remember I saw this somewhere. Can't recall whether it's an issue in Babel phabricator. Still looking for it now

Comment: @Bergi What sort of dupe are you looking for - one for ES2015 syntax, or maybe more [one like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556297/how-can-i-use-es6-syntax-such-as-let-in-chrome-console)? (or the one it itself is a dupe of)

Comment: I guess better to answer it, so that in future others can be closed duplicated @Bergi

Comment: @JamesThorpe, PSWai: I mean a SO question or answer that discusses how the parenthesis are not necessary for arrow functions

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I guess I have mixed up [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33737718/1048572) with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746615/namespacing-with-iife-in-es6/32750216#comment55431965_32750216)

Comment: @PSWai: I think I found it. Is is the one you remember?

Comment: @Bergi Not those, those two are related to async-await. I saw one that exclusively mentioning the exact issue here (or is it in my dream?). At least I can't find a dupe on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But Babel is ok with that. Why?

Because Babel is buggy :-) See https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2118 and https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2027. If I understand correctly, it was fixed with Babel 6 - it was a quite breaking change.